# Trying to Invoke a Script on a Remote Computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm having to construct some paths before attempting to invoke the script which is present on the remote computer. I'm adapting something we have working in TeamCity, but I'm currently getting the following error:

```
The command cannot be run because the File parameter requires a file path. Supply a path for the File parameter and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The command can... command again.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Relevant code below:

```
$stageScript = "D:\pkg\${dir}\stage.ps1"
$options = "production \\192.168.0.x\staging \\${server}\staging"

Invoke-Command -computername server.domain.com { powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file $stageScript $options } -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass local variables to the script block as an argument list

```
$stageScript = "D:\pkg\${dir}\stage.ps1"
$options = "production \\192.168.0.x\staging \\${server}\staging"

Invoke-Command -computername server.domain.com { powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file $args[0] $args[1] } -ArgumentList $stageScript,$options  -Credential $credential
```